# CMS for Multilingual Localization and Translation Workflow

Tags: django, internationalization, content-management-system, translation, plone

I'm helping build a multilingual website in English, Chinese and French (after in Spanish, Korean and Arabic). I've collected a database of over 2000+ entries.  It is essentially a huge product catalog (specifically travel packages) where more or less the info is the same (prices, sizes, numbers, etc.) but the labels change (of course excluding certain intro texts that must be written manually). I want to avoid having to translate piece by piece manually.

There needs to be a way for users to save the things they are interested in and rate their favorites. Also, I need an e-commerce shopping cart. Search functionality is a must since people tend to start general (one or two categories or wants) and work towards specifics. Another need is to localization and internationalization.  The other need is a specific workflow system so as content is updated and new additions are made, editors can be notified and translators can translate what needs to be done. Work flow is key since the project will involve dozens of non-technical people from around the world.

I originally tried to a work-around solution in Drupal but it seemed ill-equipped and clunky. I tried a self-built PHP CMS but the project seems to big for purely manual. I'm considering Plone and Django, but I don't have any experience working in Python, only PHP. I'm open to trying a new CMS if it meets my needs of internationalization, translation work flow, search functionality and on-going user experience.

Any suggestions on the best CMS for all this?

Answer (score 3):

Plone would be a good solution for the CMS, workflow, search and multilingual.

Ecommerce is not Plone's strength though. I would recommend integrating Plone with something like Satchmo than doing the ecommerce in Plone itself. (This has been done with success in other deployements)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a Django solution to these problems you might consider [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) or [Lightning Fast Shop](http://www.getlfs.com/) for the e-commerce part and [Pootle](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index) for the translation process...

Comment: Thanks for the response. These are definitely high-level solutions. Django with Pootle definitely offers a strong solution. I tried out Joomla with JoomFish this afternoon. I didn't feel like it got beyond Drupal's problems, especially dealing with CCK-like issues.

Comment: Definitely seems like a steep learning curve with Django unfortunately.

Comment: Well, considering the project you have taken on you probably won't find an out of the box solution, but learning Python and Django is very rewarding IMHO (I transitioned from Perl to Python three years ago and never regreted it...)